# Setting DataContext of CustomMessageBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, datacontext, windows-phone-toolkit

I need to have my **DataTemplate** of CustomMessageBox set in xaml like here:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomMessageBoxTemplate">
        <phone:LongListSelector
            LayoutMode="Grid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            GridCellSize="210 200"
            toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And I'm trying to use it in my code-behind like this:

```
CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
{
    Caption = "Title",
    DataContext = myList,
    ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.LayoutRoot.Resources["CustomMessageBoxTemplate"],
    LeftButtonContent = "OK"
};
messageBox.Show();
```

Where **myList** is correctly set List (I checked it by debugging).

But the problem is that my **DataContext** isn't changing and my LongListSelector in CustomMessageBox stays unpopulated.

I don't know where I make a mistake. I have tried to search how to do it but I haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should try setting the `ContentTemplate` before the `DataContext`

Comment: I have tried it and nothing has changed.

Comment: Right before `messageBox.Show()` DataContext is still `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the xaml inside the `ContentTemplate` automatically gets set to the `Content` property.  Try setting `Content = myList`

Comment: I can't give you upvote since my reputation is too low but very very thank you! I marked your answer as the best.